# How could I insert Young Tableaux in my questions or my answers in StackExchange (Physics, Mathematics, Tex)?

Tags: latex, mathjax

In Latex we use the package 'ytableau' and code like this

[image]

to produce Young Tableaux like these

[image]

Is there an analogue in MathJax ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax?rq=1 Make sure you read all of it...

Comment: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9744/44126