# What alternatives are available for supporting full latex equation functionality when knitting to html?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, mathjax

You can choose to convert R markdown to html (limited latex support with mathjax) or pdf output (full latex support) when using the package `knitr`, by respectively specifying in the preamble:

```
---
output:
html_document:
    mathjax: local
    self_contained: false
% other preamble
---
```

vs

```
---
output:
pdf_document:
header-includes: % lets you use full functionality of latex packages
   - \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amscd}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
% other preamble
---
```

Unfortunately as [MathJax is not latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax), packages cannot be added when publishing into html using the first method. Are there any alternatives that can typeset equations with full latex functionality in a html document? For example, is it possible to knit all equations on a separate line into an image, and then include the image automatically in the html?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what features you are missing?

Comment: I think some of the ones from the ams maths packages that allow subequations and better equation alignment.