# How to add LaTeX command definitions when compiling from RMarkdown to HTML

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, html-generation

I have a RMarkdown file and a LaTeX snippet containing bunch of latex `\newcommand` calls I want to place in *separate* file (since I want to reuse them across multiple RMarkdown files). Here's a small reproducible example: `test.rmd`

```
---
title: "Test"
---

# Test Document

## Math

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\bmat
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\emat
$$
```

and the LaTeX snippet:

```
\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\emat}{\end{bmatrix}}
```

I wish to add the LaTeX snippet in the document header and compile `test.rmd` to a standalone HTML document. How do you do this?

I have made two attempts, in attempt (1) the compiler is ignoring `header-includes` in the metadata, and in attempt (2) the `\newcommand{\bmat}{...` is shown in the browser as plain-text. Both of these attempts work when compiling to PDF (i.e. replacing `rmarkdown::html_document` by `rmarkdown::pdf_document`). I suspect this is because MathJax works very differently from LaTeX compilers but I haven't found a very clear explanation on StackOverflow or [docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html) about this...

### Attempt 1

Define `common.yaml` YAML metadata file for Pandoc

```
---
urlcolor: blue
header-includes: |
  \newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{bmatrix}}
  \newcommand{\emat}{\end{bmatrix}}
---
```

then I compile `test.rmd` by doing

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.rmd',quiet=TRUE,output_format=rmarkdown::html_document(pandoc_args=c('--metadata-file=/current/working/dir/common.yaml')))"
```

### Attempt 2

Define `header.tex` header file for Pandoc

```
\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\emat}{\end{bmatrix}}
```

then I compile `test.rmd` by doing

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.rmd',quiet=TRUE,output_format=rmarkdown::html_document(pandoc_args=c('--include-in-header=/current/working/dir/header.tex')))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my question. Do attempt (2), except header has to be an HTML file, say `header.html` with contents

```
\(
\newcommand{\bmat}{\begin{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\emat}{\end{bmatrix}}
\)
```

Note the use of `\(` and `\)`. Now I can use

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.rmd',quiet=TRUE,output_format=rmarkdown::html_document(pandoc_args=c('--include-in-header=/current/working/dir/header.html')))"
```

Note that it's not possible to add `\usepackage` in the snippet as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax).